# WCF migration from .Net 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: wcf

Just Migrated and now I am getting the following error message...

*The message with Action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).*

Little else has changed from the 3.5 release, which worked. I am using SSL, TransportWithMessageCredential and client Credentials = "UserName"
Server side config is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
   <service name="BPA.SCA.CFI.CFIWcfService" 
behaviorConfiguration="defaultSecure">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="https://rdSlice.dev.local/SCACFI/"/>
        <!-- <add baseAddress="https://rdSlice.dev.local/SCACFI/"/> -->
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    bindingNamespace="https://rdSlice.bpa.gov"
    bindingConfiguration="SecureTransport"
            contract="BPA.SCA.CFIService.IManageSCACFI" >
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="mex" 
    binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
    contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultSecure">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
  <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
  <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication
          userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
          membershipProviderName="SCASqlMembershipProvider" />
      </serviceCredentials>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
     <binding name="SecureTransport" 
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
           <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
           <message establishSecurityContext="false" 
        clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>

       </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You show your base address as `https://rdSlice.dev,local/SCACFI/` - should it be `https://rdSlice.dev.local/SCACFI/` instead? (note the change from a comma to a period)

Comment: yes, that was just a typo in my question... Not that way on server.  Thx, fixed it..